# Make BeautifulSoup honor xml:space="preserve"

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse XML:

```
In [64]: b = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<xml><t xml:space="preserve">     </t><t xml:space="preserve">  A  </t></xml>', 'xml')
In [65]: b.find_all('t')
Out[65]: [<t xml:space="preserve"> </t>, <t xml:space="preserve">  A  </t>]
```

As a result, 5 spaces are collapsed into 1 in the first `t` tag, despite the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute.

Is there a way to make BeautifulSoup to respect `xml:space="preserve"` and not collapse the spaces?

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you a direct answer regarding BeautifulSoup. However, `lxml` can do  this for you.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.fromstring('<xml><t xml:space="preserve">     </t><t xml:space="preserve">  A  </t></xml>')
>>> [_.text for _ in tree.findall('t')]
['     ', '  A  ']
```